# Setting up SOCKS5 proxy on browser for using on other apps

Tags: browser, https, proxy, vpn, socks

I have a VPN that only connect through HTTPS on my browser with its extension. I'm using Windows 10 and I'm looking for a solution like Tor Browser that have a SOCKS5 proxy (127.0.0.1:9150) and other apps can use it to bypass censorship.
Is there any solution for Firefox, Chrome or any other browser that after connecting to VPN extension, other apps can use a SOCKS5 or HTTP proxy to connect through it?

I tried Proxifier and similar apps on Windows 10 and no luck. But official VPN browser extension and FoxyProxy work.
I tried different ISPs and I know my firewall is not the problem and VPN is connected on other ISPs.
VPN name: TorGuard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I found so far is to use v2rayA (https://v2raya.org/en/).
First you connect to your HTTPS proxy through this app and then you can use HTTP or SOCKS5 proxy that it gives you to connect other apps or use Proxifier (https://www.proxifier.com/download/) to tunnel all traffic.

P.S. The default address and port of v2rayA are:
HTTP 127.0.0.1:20171
SOCKS5 127.0.0.1:20170